# Can't open Visual Studio Code from Start Menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-defender

I've recently uninstalled VS 2015 and some other packages which I don't recall. Ever since the uninstallation I've not been able to view the the icon of VS Code, VS Code Insider and Windows Defender. All those software were working properly previously.

[[image: Icons of VS Code and Winodws Defender not shown]

If I click on those application, they won't open.

But if I selected a file or folder and open them by selecting the option "Open with VS Code or VS Code Insiders", there is no any problem. The icon of those software can't be seen on the taskbar too even if they are opened.

What package should I need to install again to make them appear? What other software might be affected?